# Is there any way to run locally site which is available on ssh?

Tags: virtualbox, ssh

Not long ago I've installed `hadoop` on `VBox Ubuntu 14.04 server`. I'm working with this VM via ssh. I run some map-reduce tasks and now I want to check statistics of their execution. This statistics should be available via such url http://localhost:50030/. But I can't open it at VBox, because it's server.

I'm using such command to connect to VB:

```
ssh -p 2223 vk@127.0.0.1
```

Is there any way how I can open this url on my local machine?

Comment: Have you tried port-forwarding feature of VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up SOCKS5 proxy using:

```
ssh -D 9999 -p 2223 vk@127.0.0.1
```

and then set up your browser to use SOCKS5 proxy on 127.0.0.1:9999. You should be able to access `localhost:50030` from the browser from this time.

But rather easier way is to set up local-port-forwarding:

```
ssh -L 50030:localhost:50030 -p 2223 vk@127.0.0.1
```

which makes your remote port accessible as a local and you will be able to connect directly to your service using `localhost:50030` url.

Comment: I'm getting this `Bad local forwarding specification '500030:localhost:500030'`

Comment: sorry, too much zeroes. It should work with `50030:localhost:50030`

Comment: After execution `ssh -L 50030:localhost:50030 -p 2223 vk@127.0.0.1` it prompts me for a password. After I enter it, it logins to ssh. I'm trying to open url but getting 404. At console I can see `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`. Also, I have opened ssh connection at separate tab (if it matters).

Comment: It might matter how the routing between virtual host and your machine is set up. You might try different local port (`5003:localhost:50030`) and then connecting to `localhost:5003` or just set up the same port forwarding as you have for the `ssh` (using IPTABLES?).

Comment: Still can't handle it. For ssh I'm using first answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host

Comment: Can you add the whole verbose log (`-vvv`) from the command in my answer to your edited question, to see how and where it actually fails? VBox port forwarding will probably not work, since the service will be listening only on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to add host-only network adapter to your VB machine

VirtualBox meny -> Machine -> Settings -> Network -> Adapter -> Host-only Adapter

as soon as it sets up ip (192.168.56.101 for me, may be different for you) for VB you can connect to your VB from Host via ssh or browser

good luck